# How to buffer PDF pages on CALayers in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, pdf, calayer, pdf-rendering

I am working on a PDFReader application.I am making use of CALayer to render the pdf contents.currently one pdf page is being rendered at a time and is displayed on the visible view.I want to buffer few pages(say one previous page and one next page for example) in advance while the user is reading the current page.Can any one please suggest me a better way of achieving this buffering mechanism?Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look at this open source PDF viewer for iOS, it implements the features you asked about: http://www.vfr.org/2011/09/pdf-reader-viewer-v2-2/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to draw some content in the background, you can look into using the Grand Central Dispatch API, and drawing using Core Graphics commands. You will need to be careful about thread safety, such as checking/waiting for the background drawing to finish before trying to the push the results to the display.

I found a quite useful post, [Image manipulation and drawing using Quartz in the background threads](http://www.codingventures.com/2009/08/image-manipulation-and-drawing-using-quartz-in-the-background-threads/), on ensuring that you only use thread safe commands to create your drawing context (the example creates a bitmap context, but obviously you will be looking to create a PDF context using `CGPDFContextCreate` or similar).